# Touch screen suggestion

Tags: touch, touchscreen

I am getting interested into touch screen programming and want to try something for fun. Searched for some time and looking for an infrared but still feel like found no hardware. Anybody could suggest an affordable and good touch screen also which type of touch screens is most suitable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Play with HTML5/javascript on an iPad. Most (if not all) touchscreen functionality is supported in web pages. Although it doesn't use multi-touch, check out [avatarbouquet.com](http://www.avatarbouquet.com) on an iPad or handheld iOS device, or use [this link](http://avatarbouquet.com/?iPad) to check out the code in your desktop browser. Similarly, many Android tablets allow javascript to process touch gestures in this manner. Basically, you use `touchstart`, `touchmove` etc, where you normally would have used `mousemove` etc.

Alternatively, buy an embedded system, such as an Arduino 2560 Mega, and hook something like [this touch screen](http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=55) up to it. It's a much more constrained environment, so this might be more than you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use Raspberry Pi, go with a touch screen from Waveshare.  I've tried other touchscreens from companies on Amazon, but only Waveshare was really reliable.